# How to pass variable in sql in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

i've used this sql query to get data between the time interval

```
$start_time = $_POST['i_date'].' 07:00:00';
$end_time = $_POST['i_date'].' 14:00:00';
/*echo $start_time;
die();*/
$sql = 'select * from datetime where code = 1001 and time between '.$start_time.' and '.$end_time;
```

but i am getting following error message:
**Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:00:00 and 2015-09-09 14:00:00' at line 1**

Comment: '...07:00:00 and 2015-09-09 14:00:00' -> '...07:00:00' and '2015-09-09 14:00:00'

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements and bind variables, then you don't need to remember to quote values

Answer (score 4):

Your query has an error try this

```
$sql = "select * from datetime where code = 1001 and time between '".$start_time."' and '".$end_time."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put the semicolon inside the string you're passing:

```
$sql = 'select * from datetime where code = 1001 and time between '.$start_time.' and '.$end_time. ';';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind them in single quotes:

```
$sql = "select * from datetime where 
code = 1001 and time between 
'$start_time' and '$end_time'";
```